# Casting Java ArrayList<Custom Class> to ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to convert an `ArrayList` of class `SomeClass` to an `ArrayList` of class `Object`. This new `ArrayList` of `Object` will then be passed to a function. I currently have done the following:

```
// convert ArrayList<SomeClass> to generic ArrayList<Object>

Object[] objectArray = someClassList.toArray();
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
    objects.add(objectArray[i]);
}

someFunction(objects);

public void someFunction(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    // do something with objects
}
```

Is there a more efficient or "standard" way of doing this? Is what I am doing "wrong" in the first place?

The purpose of converting it to `ArrayList` of class `Object` is that I have created an external library to process `ArrayList` of generic `Object`s.

Comment: Can you change the library that wants `ArrayList<Object>` input? It should probably be taking something like `ArrayList<?>` or `List<?>`.

Comment: Why not pass the original `ArrayList<Something>` directly, with a cast?

Comment: What external processing are you trying to do?

Comment: just do `void someFunction(ArrayList<?> objects)`. It's effectively a list of objects then. You can't cast between generic types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Great thanks. That points me in the right direction for some more research regarding the use of ArrayList<?>.

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to change the function's signature to taking an `ArrayList<? extends Object> objects` or an `ArrayList<?> objects` (or even better, `List` instead of `ArrayList`), you will be able to pass your `ArrayList<SomeClass>` directly.

The reason an `ArrayList<SomeClass>` is *not* an `ArrayList<Object>` is that an `ArrayList<Object>` would accept that you `add()` *any* kind of `Object` into it, which is not something you can do with an `ArrayList<SomeClass>`. On the other hand, an `ArrayList<? extends Object>` will allow you to retrieve elements from the list, but not add elements, so `ArrayList<SomeClass>` can safely be assigned to it.

Comment: I want to add the fact that `ArrayList<?>` is actually an abbreviation for `ArrayList<? extends Object>` -- they denote exactly the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you created the external library, I think it would be easier to modify the function signature to accept lists of any type. This can be accomplished using the [unbounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) `?`:

```
public static void someFunction(List<?> objects) {
    // whatever
}
```

Then you don't need to make any conversions to call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    someFunction(words);
}
```

Also, unless you have a good reason not to, it would be better to accept any `List` in `someFunction` instead of limiting your input to `ArrayList`s. This makes your code more flexible and easier to change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to transform the type parameters of a type in arbitrary ways with two casts:

```
ArrayList<SomeClass> l1 = ...;
ArrayList<Object> l2 = (ArrayList<Object>) (Object) l1;
```

But, as Aasmund Eldhuset also says in his answer: **This is probably not a good idea!** It is better to give a more suitable type to `l2` instead, like `ArrayList<?>`.

This code gives you an compile warning saying `Type safetyThat: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Object>` for a reason. If for example a `String` is added to `l2` and then someone reads `l1` and expects a `SomeClass` they will get a very unexpected `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to convert a `List<SubFoo>` to a `List<Foo>` is to use `Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfSubFoos)`, which is perfectly type-safe and actually enforces that you can't do anything bad with it (like adding a `DifferentSubFoo`).